# nginx regex with multiple options

Tags: regex, nginx

I would to make a Regex (I use Nginx) to have something like this :

Example of output :

```
/m/signup
/en/signup
/fr/m/signup
/en/m/signup
```

I tried something like this :

```
rewrite ^/(m|(fr|en)|(fr|en)\/m)/(signup|otherpage)$ /$2.php?p=$1 last;
```

the parameter "p" should be either "m", or "en", or "fr", or "fr/m" for example.

but it doesn't want to work..

Any idea ?

Comment: What if you use `^/((?:fr|en|m)(?:/(?:fr|en|m))?)/(signup)$`? It will also match `/fr/fr/signup` or `/m/m/signup` though - is it OK? Also, try [`^/((?:en|fr)/m|m|(?:en|fr))/(signup)$`](https://regex101.com/r/qU7tI7/1). Or is the problem in capturing the language abbreviation?

Comment: thank you Wiktor, your second regex works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^/((?:en|fr)/m|m|(?:en|fr))/(signup|otherpage)$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qU7tI7/2)

I used this instead of `(m|(fr|en)|(fr|en)\/m)`:

- `(?:en|fr)/m` - either `en` or `fr` followed with `/m`
- `|` - or...
- `m` - just `m`
- `|` - or...
- `(?:en|fr) - either`en`or`fr`

Comment: Thnak you very much Wiktor!